# get/set methods and encapsulation in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, get, encapsulation, getter

I've often seen the following described as the "correct" way of implementing get/set methods:

```
public class Foo {
    private var _someVar:SomeClass;

    public function get someVar():SomeClass {
       return _someVar;
    }

    public function set someVar(newValue:SomeClass):void {
      _someVar = newValue;
    }
}
```

Now, because AS3 is returning always references to Object classes, when we use the "get" method we obtain a reference to our ***private*** var => encapsulation is broken.

Even if we don't have a set method we can modify the privar var !
What is the purpose of setting it as private then?

The only solution that I found to this is to return a clone of "_someVar" in our get method, but I've never seen this in any example.
So I think I'm losing something here.

Are you returning a clone object from your getters or you just accepting the break in encapsulation?

**EDIT**
I understand how set and get methods works, and I understand the benefits of them.
I'm asking for the break of "private" access in our private var when we return it with a getter by **reference** (if our var is of type Number, String, int, etc AS3 is returning always by value, not reference, so we don't have problem here).
Maybe is not the encapsulation which is broken, because we can't set the property without a setter method. But we can modify it !

See this example:

```
public class Foo {
    private var _someVar:Array; // note that this is a Object (not Number, String, etc)

    public function Foo(){
        _someVar = ['don't touch this!'];
    }

    public function get someVar():SomeClass {
       return _someVar;
    }

    // note that we don't have a setter

}


var f:Foo = new Foo(); 
var a:Array = f.someVar;
trace(a[0]); //  'don't touch this!'
a[0] = 'why not?'; 
trace(f.someVar[0]); // 'why not'
```

So, we are changing our private var from outside, and without control, even when we don't have a setter method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are controlling access to the member variable when you use get/set functions.  For example, if you want the variable to be "read-only" from the outside, but editable from within the class instance you make a get function so that it can be read from outside but do NOT create a set function.  This is different from using a private const, because that must be declared immediately and can never be changed from anywhere.

Similarly, using these functions can allow you to create side-effects for setting the property.  For instance:

```
public function set foo(value:*):void{
    _foo = value;
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("fooSet")); 
    // setting foo alerts interested parties
    // that the value of foo has changed
    // without them having to poll foo.
}
```

EDIT : Because you've updated the question to be more specific, here's an update of my own.

You normally would NOT do that.  If you're trying to protect the variable itself, then you won't offer access to it directly.  Doing that breaks "the law of Demeter".  For your specific example with the array, you might do something like this:

```
private var _someArray = [true,false];

function get someArray():Array{
    return _someArray.slice(); // Returns a clone of the original array.
}
```

As a different example, using a theoretical complex object...

```
private var _someObject:SomeObject;

function get someObject():SomeObject{
    return _someObject; // "Wrong."  It breaks the law of demeter.
}

////// instead, you would do this.....

function get getSomeObjectsInt():int{
    return _someObject.foo; // where .foo is an int
} 


////// or this....

function doStuffWithFooObject():Boolean{
   return _someObject.doSomething(); // where doSomething returns a boolean;
}


///// or this.....

function performActionOnData(pData:String):String{
    return _someObject.someActionWithString(pData); 
}
```

That last one is interesting because you don't need to expose to the world that you're using SomeObject to do the work... you're just advertising that you yourself can do it.

Comment: I think I need to edit my question, obviously I'm not explaining it well :) sorry for that, English is not my first language :(

Comment: yes, I think it confirms what I was asking: if we want to give only read access to a property and its content it's not enough with setting that property as private and not defining a setter, we also need to return a "copy" (value, clone) of our private property in our getter.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the private variable from within the class it belongs to, but you can't modify it from outside that class.

Having getter and setter methods gives you more power (as a developer) over the class.

Your application will grow and at some point you may want your class to be able to do something with a value before it retrieves it or before sets it. You may also want your class to be able to call a method every time it sets a value. Things like that, you can easily achieve when you have getter / setter methods.

Additionally, as TheDarkIn1978 says, leaving one of the methods out, could make the variable write-only or read-only which would be of a huge benefit to encapsulation.

Comment: Encapsulation isn't preventing classes to have a reference on private attribute. It's about controlling what attributes other classes can access to. It think that what the OP didn't really get.

Comment: It's not just about controlling what attributes other classes can access. It's also about controlling the ways attributes are accessed.

Comment: That's not true, if I don't have a setter, only a getter, I can modify (not set) the private var anyway, because my getter is returning a reference to that private member not a copy! So, I'm changing the private var from outside my class, without control. Maybe the word is not "encapsulation", but we are bypassing the access restriction.

Comment: @Enrique: yes you are right, the same goes for C#, C++, Java, etc. What you can't do is create a new object with the getter, you need the setter for that.

Comment: Along with this, you are probably realizing you often don't need a setter; you only need a setter if you need the outside to be able to change the private variable's reference.

Comment: @Enrique, you can modify the object, but you can't modify the variable. Whatever you do to the object outside the class, the variable will still hold a reference to that object.

Comment: @sixfeetsix: in C++ you return always a value by default, and you can choose to return a reference too. @Emanuil: yes, I know we can't set a new reference, but we can change the values, so it's not completely "read only", and I know that is the expected result (in C++ if we return a reference we have the same), the question was about this practice, because the only solution that I see for this is making a clone (with a custom function) in our getter and return that clone instead a reference if you want a var (and it's content) strict read only

Comment: @Enrique, what does your reply have to do with your question? At this point I'll just side with the first comment to your question from The_asMan.

Comment: well, I come from C++, and there you return values by default and if you want to return a reference you must make it explicit, AS3 is returning references always and to return values the only way (apparently) is to make a custom clone, but I've never seen that in getter methods (or at least is not a common practice), and that was confusing me because if we can't return a value we can't make a "real" read only property (I called this encapsulation but maybe that's not the proper term).

Answer (score 0):

I often use getters and setters if I need to know if that variable has been modified in order to change other things.

For example if I would have :

```
public var prop : Number;
private var prop2 : Number;
```

and I want that prop2 to be at any time = prop + 10, I wouldn't know when to update prop2, but I could do something like this:

```
private var _prop : Number;
private var _prop2 : Number;

public function set prop(newValue : Number):void {
  _prop = newValue;
  _prop2 = prop + 10;
}
```

Comment: Hi @gabitzish, this is not my question, I understand how set and get method works. Also, you are using Number in your example, Number is returned by value in AS3 not reference, so we are not breaking the private access if our var is Number (or int, String, Bool, etc)

Answer (score 0):

the code above is exactly the same as simply writing:

```
public var someVar:SomeClass;
```

if, however, you wanted to make this variable **read-only** or **write-only**, you would supply a public getter or public setter for the private variable respectively.

in addition, setters and getter functions allow you to manage passed parameters, fire off events, etc.  for example, let's assume you have a variable `mySmallNumber:Number` that should only accept values less than 10:

```
private var mySmallNumberProperty:Number;

public function set mySmallNumber(value:Number):void
     {
     if     (value < 10)
            mySmallNumberProperty = value;
            else
            throw new ArgumentError("mySmallNumber must be less than 10");
     }

public function get mySmallNumber():Number
     {
     return mySmallNumberProperty;
     }
```

- please don't lash out at me for not conforming to the use of the underscore prefix.  it's a matter of style.  while it's "standard" i also think it's super ugly.

Comment: Again, your private var is of type Number, there's no problem there because AS3 is returning Number as value, not as reference. Make your mySmallNumberProperty of type "Array" for example and you can't make it read only anymore, because you are returning a reference to that private var from your getter and hence you can modify it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for encapsulation then you shouldn't provide direct access to complex objects (passed by ref). You should look at what it is you expect other classes to be able to do with your 'SomeClass'. If you really need to pass a whole class and don't want it to be a ref, then add a clone method. If you just expect other classes to update some data that belongs to 'SomeClass' the provide setters for that data and apply it directly to the 'SomeClass' instance. It does require more code, but will accomplish the goal of encapsulating your class.